# Model pivot not attaching properly after detaching all

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a custom developed user/roles functionality with a roles table and a user_roles intermediate table. The user_roles table also has some additional data.

Lets suppose a user currently has 1 role assigned to him, and i have to assign 2 more roles to this user. Mostly i just detach all pivot enteries for the user, and then add all 3 roles again. This simplifies things and i dont have to check the json data for duplicate enteries. Something like this.

```
$user->roles()->detach();
```

**This works fine and all the user pivot entries are removed. But when i attach all 3 roles again to the user, only the new ones are added.** This is really weird and have been trying to debug it for a few hours now.

I loop through all 3 roles and i made sure that the loop is actually receiving this data properly.

```
$apps = json_encode(array('app1','app2'));
$user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['apps' => $apps]);
```

I remember that i faced a very similar issue earlier on another project as well, but dont remember the solution. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Instead of attaching/detaching, have you tried looking at sync? Not sure if this will fix your issue, but it's definitely handy to know.

Comment: thanks karl. I have commented on codearts answer as to why using sync is a bit complicated in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sync()` method. You need the ids of the roles that you want to assign. Lets say you have some checkboxes holding the role ids.

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
<input type="checkbox" name=role[] value="{{ $role->id }}"
@endforeach
```

Then in your controller:

```
 $user-roles()->sync($request['roles']); //$request['roles'] contains the ids of the new roles you want to assign
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i know about sync. But using it over here will become more complicated because i will have to query first to get the current roles and then assign new ones. And they have alot of additional json fields that also need to be calculated before adding them. I am looking for a simple explaination to why this happens, because i faced a similar issue on another project as well.

Comment: Hmm I am pretty sure I ran into the same problem a few days ago and I fixed it using sync. However you could try writing $user->save() after the detaching. Might work.

Comment: well i guess syncing was the right thing to do so i modified my code for syncing and it worked. Didn't try your other suggestion regarding saving user though, but i remember now that this was indeed what i did in my other project.